# How can I open .dictionary files on OSX?

Tags: macos, file-extension, dictionary

I'd like to have a look at the files that the Dictionary App that comes with macOS uses. I was able to locate the files, they're of the `.dictionary` format. How can I open them, if at all?

Comment: Have you tried textedit.app? What exact files? Add the path to them in your original question.

Answer (score 2):

As described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912781/os-x-dictionary-format-information) `.dictionary` are bundles not files. These bundles are special macOS directories that Finder shows as single objects.  Contents can be shown by right click and "Show Package Contents".

[image: Package Contents]

The list of words is in `Body.data` within this directory.  For example for the included *Oxford Dictionary of English* this is stored at:

```
/System/Library/AssetsV2/com_apple_MobileAsset_DictionaryServices_dictionaryOSX/26e585a43423edb02b25fa7ba9af3fdc08eed6d7.asset/AssetData/Oxford Dictionary of English.dictionary/Contents/Resources/Body.data
```

This is a binary file created from the dictionary .xml described in the Apple  [Dictionary Services Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/DictionaryServicesProgGuide/prepare/prepare.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006152-CH3-SW23) using the [Dictionary Development Kit](https://github.com/SebastianSzturo/Dictionary-Development-Kit).

These files are designed for use with the Apple dictionary app and don't contain plain text so can't be simply read with a text editor or other program.

Answer (score 0):

[`reverse_data.py`](https://github.com/fab-jul/parse_dictionaries/blob/main/reverse_data.py) from [`parse_dictionaries`](https://github.com/fab-jul/parse_dictionaries) can be used to extract individual entries from dictionaries. There is an accompanying blog posting describing the [technical background](https://fmentzer.github.io/posts/2020/dictionary/).

[`apple-dictionary`](https://github.com/JadedTuna/apple-dictionary) can be used to extract an entire dictionary.

For a usage examples see my [other answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/449571/10074).